# Where do you find email for Minecraft account in .minecraft files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Forgot my Microsoft email for my Minecraft account. Tried looking in the .minecraft json files but couldn't find anything. I know it was possible in the past but maybe it isn't now through Microsoft? Any help to find it would be appreciated.
I've looked at previous questions and they mention a launcher_profiles.json file but that file contains much different information now with just profiles of Minecraft versions you have played.
There is a launcher_msa_credentials.bin file that I think might have it but I have no idea.

Comment: Some tools (Notepad++ comes to mind) have an option to "Search in files". You could specify your %appdata%\.minecraft folder and have it search for "@" in any files there. It's a long shot and will only work for plain text files (such as a JSON), but worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

1. Search up the "%appdata%" folder.
2. Head into ".minecraft"
3. Go to the "launcher_profiles" folder inside .minecraft and it should show all the emails of all the profiles connected to your launcher.

Comment: There is no launcher_profiles "folder" but I'm pretty sure you meant the .json file. That file just contains the different version profiles *of minecraft* I have created (1.8, 1.16). It doesn't actually contain any of the account profiles. What does contain them is the launcher_accounts.json file, but no sign of the emails, only a few uuid keys. I believe things changed after microsoft required users to make a microsoft account instead of a mojang account, hence launcher_msa_credentials.bin (microsoft store account credentials). Tried to mount the file to open it but no luck.